Why is there a bias of 127 in IEEE 754 format when a bias of 128 works as well?
We started with IEEE 754 representation of floating point no.s in college . A major point of this representation is that it wants to reserve the extreme values 0 and 255 corresponding to all zeros and all ones for special no.s, which is alright . But why the bias 127 for it ?
So in 8 bits the exponent can take values from -128 to 127 , which effectively translates to 0 to 255 after adding 128 to each . Now we want to separate 0 and 255 which leaves us with 1 to 254 .
Here the IEEE 754 representation uses a bias of 127 , so the actual range of exponents becomes from -126 to 127.
If we have a bias of 128 , the range of actual exponents will be from -127 to 126.
What is the problem with the latter case , because we are still achieving to reserve 0 and 255 for special cases . Besides it looks better as we take out the extreme values from -128 to 127 to get -127 to 126?

Good question!  The explanations I've read say that the bias is chosen so that the range is "balanced", meaning that as much as possible, each representable number's multiplicative inverse is also representable.  A bias of 128, as you suggest, would give a (normalized) range of 5.87747e-39 to 1.70141e+38. But since 1 / 5.87747e-39 is 1.70141e+38, that would actually be perfectly balanced!  (Better, that is, than the range with a bias of 127.) So there must be something else going on.  Perhaps chux or njuffa or Eric P. will be along to answer — they know a lot about floating point.

Does this answer your question? Why the value of biased exponent is 127 instead of 128?

@SteveSummit Use 9+ digits for your range and quotient to see 1.0f/FLT_MIN > FLT_MAX in your example (a reason that a bias of 128 has weaknesses.)

@chux-ReinstateMonica Thanks for the response.  I shouldn't have said "perfectly balanced", but it seemed more nearly so.  With a bias of 127, 1/FLT_MAX pushes you well down into the subnormals.  So I guess the thinking was, having 1/FLT_MAX << FLT_MIN was preferable to having 1/FLT_MIN even slightly greater than FLT_MAX.

@BrettHale yes it does , so basically with a bias of 128 you have an overflow occuring for the 1.0/min_normal case , but with 127 we don't have that , although we step into the territory of subnormals for the 1.0/max case . We can utilise the subnormals that way , makes sense !
